# How to extract phase angle from sinusoid

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, complex, trigonometry

I'm doing some electric circuit calcualtions and I'm trying to get the phasor representation of some arbitrary function of Sin or Cos. Could be complex like:

```
(0. - 10. I) Sin[1000 t]
```

For instance, if I have:

```
Vin = 10Cos[1000t- 90Degree]
```

which is:

```
Vin = 10Re[Exp[-I*90Degree]*Exp[I*1000t]]
```

I want to get the magnitude angle form. i.e $10\angle-90^\circ$

I can get the magnitude with:

```
MaxValue[Abs[Vin], t]
```

but I can't get the phase angle correctly. I've tried:

```
Re[N[ArcCos[(Vin/MaxValue[Vin, t]) /. t -> 0]/Degree]]
```

but that gives $90^\circ$ not $-90^\circ$

So I have 2 questions actually:

1. Can I force mathematica to keep my function in $\cos\left(something - 90^\circ\right)$ form instead of changing it to $\sin\left(something + 0^\circ\right)$?
2. And how can I correctly obtain the phase angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could expand the `Vin` to Fourier series to *"normalize"* it.

For example there are three of them kind:

```
VinSet = {10 Cos[1000 t - π/2], 9 Cos[400 t + π/4], Cos[t + 3.45]};

coeffSet = FourierCoefficient[# /. Times[ω_?NumericQ t] :> t, t, 1] & /@ VinSet
```

> $\left\{-5 i,\frac{9 \sqrt[4]{-1}}{2}, -0.476409-0.151771 i\right \}$

```
{2 Abs[#], Arg[#]} & /@ coeffSet
```

> {$\left\{10,-\frac{\pi }{2}\right\}$,$\left\{9,\frac{\pi }{4}\right\}$,$\{1.,-2.83319\}$}

Note $2\pi-2.83319 \approx 3.45$.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the angle as a real number (rather than an exact integer), it does not do the transformation to `Sin`. For instance

```
Vin = 10 Cos[1000 t - Pi/2.0]
```

and

```
Vin = 10 Cos[1000 t - 90.0 Degree]
```

both do what you ask.

Comment: Great that works, any idea how to obtain the phase angle?

Answer (score 1):

As for your second question, here's one way that is very similar to what we'd do by hand. Use the exponential form and then identify the phase and magnitude.

```
Clear[A, p, t]
Vin = 10 Exp[-Pi/2]*Exp[1000 t I];
{A, p} = Replace[Vin, A_ Exp[p_] -> {A Exp[Re[p]], Im[p]}]
```

A now holds the amplitude and p holds the phase. If you have the trigonometric form you can use `FullSimplify` to bring it into the exponential form first.

To get rid of `Im[t]` and `Re[t]` we can tell *Mathematica* that the variable t is a real variable:

```
Refine[{A, p}, Assumptions :> t \[Element] Reals]
```